# images not labeled after import vertexAI image object detection

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I'm using this example to import my images and annotation data (JSONL file) into my vertexAI dataset:
https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/samples/aiplatform-import-data-image-object-detection-sample

```html
from google.cloud import aiplatform
import os

#https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/samples/aiplatform-import-data-image-object-detection-sample
def import_data_image_object_detection_sample(
        project: str = proj,
        dataset_id: str = datasetID,
        gcs_source_uri: str = cloudURIToInputFile,
        location: str = "us-central1",
        api_endpoint: str = "us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com",
        timeout: int = 1800,
):
    # The AI Platform services require regional API endpoints.
    client_options = {"api_endpoint": api_endpoint}
    # Initialize client that will be used to create and send requests.
    # This client only needs to be created once, and can be reused for multiple requests.
    client = aiplatform.gapic.DatasetServiceClient(client_options=client_options)
    import_configs = [
        {
            "gcs_source": {"uris": [gcs_source_uri]},
            "import_schema_uri": "gs://google-cloud-aiplatform/schema/dataset/ioformat/image_bounding_box_io_format_1.0.0.yaml",
        }
    ]
    name = client.dataset_path(project=project, location=location, dataset=dataset_id)
    response = client.import_data(name=name, import_configs=import_configs)
    print("Long running operation:", response.operation.name)
    import_data_response = response.result(timeout=timeout)
    print("import_data_response:", import_data_response)


import_data_image_object_detection_sample()
```

After I run this, all of the images are uploaded successfully, but none of the labels show up on the images. I was able to import them all successfully with the labels the other day, so I am not sure what is happening now. Thanks

Comment: Did you get this to work? I am finding the same thing: creation works but updates do not.

Comment: I found a similar thing, when I selected a jsonl file from google cloud everything came up fine, but when I added new images to a data set through the API there were no labels / bounding boxes.  The reason for that is that the API import was creting its own annotation set,  so if i selected that annotation set the images uploaded through the API were labelled but all the ones already in the set were not.  I've not figured out how to specify the annotation set yet though